# Density of States (DOS) to energy graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, density-of-states

I am trying to find the amount of electrons in a conduction band in Si (Silicon), all I've got is a graph similar to this one:

[image]

I've tried to integrate like this:
$$ N = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\exp(E-E_f)} \cdot D(E)\text d E$$

However, I have a hard time finding what $D(E)$ is supposed to be. If i put is as:
$D(E) = C \cdot \sqrt{E}$, where $C = \text{const.}$
The integral becomes unsolvable.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Isn't $D(E)$ just the function plotted in your graph?

Comment: Yes, but in order to solve the integral, I need an expression for it.

Comment: Ok, so digitize the graph, then. For example: https://datathief.org/

Comment: What is the temperature? What is the chemical potential? How can you take something like $\exp(E-E_f)$ where $E$ is a dimensionfull energy (I assume that this is what it is)?

Comment: Try calculating the effective density of states https://kx.lumerical.com/t/calculating-the-effective-density-of-states/33974 at 300K you should get a number around 3e19/cm^3

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that the temperature is 300K, the task is to find the solution with a pen and paper so I don't want to digitalize the graph.

However, I think I got it.  I need to find the function D(E) for each appropiate interval and then integrate that expression, then simply add the answers I get.
The question I got asked me to make reasonable approximations of D(E) for each interval, somehow missed that part.